# Network keeps disconnecting

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, 13.04

My Internet works fine when I'm at home. it works fine doing lunch also, except doing lunch. my connection to the Internet has problems. I'm assuming that this is because everyone is using the Internet at the same time, however, no one else has this problem that I have.

The problem with the Internet is I get frequently disconnected from the Internet, then my computer tries to connect for a while, constantly asking me for the network password, until it's able to connect, then it will stay connected for a while, until it suddenly disconnects again. this continues to repeat until lunch is over, then it works fine.

Some other notes: The majority of people using the Internet is on a Mac. I'm guessing the modem itself is a Mac product, but I'm not certain. I don't know how close to the modem I am, but other people would be in the same room as me, and their Internet works just fine.

This problem was happening while I was using Ubuntu 12.10, I decided to upgrade to the beta release of Ubuntu 13.04 to see if the problem was fixed in a more stable release of Ubuntu, but the problem still persists.

I'm assuming this could also be a hardware driver issue. I don't really know what this means, or if it is helpful, but this is the information about networking with my laptop I could find.

```
Integrated 802.11 b/g/n
Built-in Bluetooth™ V3.0+HS (Optional)
10/100/1000 Base T
```

Can anyone describe to me what could be going on, and if there are any workarounds to get this working again?

Comment: Are using a static IP or getting one assigned from DHCP?

Comment: I'm not using a static ip.

Comment: turns out, this problem happens in windows also, so it seems like it is a hardware problem.